# Why is #region a directive and not a comment?

Tags: visual-studio, language-design

I assume #region is ignored and dropped by the compiler, so why is it a preprocessor directive rather than some kind of comment structure (like //REGION NAME: stuff(); //ENDREGION NAME or something.) Is there a particular reason the decision to make it a directive was made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's not a direct answer but that's how it's laid out in the [C# Language Spec](http://bit.ly/CSSpecDL) (§2.5).

> The pre-processing directives provide the ability to conditionally
>   skip sections of source files, to report error and warning conditions,
>   and to delineate distinct regions of source code.

I don't think it's ignored by the compiler, it just doesn't have any effect. It's still considered a conditional compilation from the lexical processing point of view and, therefore, in line with some of the other pre-processing directives. From the spec:

> The lexical processing of a region:
>
> #region
>
> ...
>
> #endregion
>
> corresponds exactly to the lexical processing of a conditional compilation directive of the form:
>
> #if true
>
> ...
>
> #endif